# NaN on ajax request returned data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, reactjs

on the php side of the api I have this:

```
$res = $db->query("SELECT count(upVote) FROM tbl_post_likers WHERE post_id='$pnum' AND upVote='true'");
$row = $res->fetchArray();
if($row[0] > 0){
    $upVotes = $row[0];
    $res = $db->query("SELECT count(downVote) FROM tbl_post_likers WHERE post_id='$pnum' AND downVote='true'");
    $row = $res->fetchArray();
    $downVotes = $row[0];

    $tot = $upVotes + $downVotes;
    $upVotesPer = ($upVotes * 100) / $tot;
    $downVotesPer = ($downVotes * 100) / $tot;
    return $upVotesPer - $downVotesPer;
}else if ($row[0] == 0){
    return 0;
}
```

and I've tried to return some more data as an array from the api.
and on the javascript side when I `JSON.parse` the returned data I get all the data correctly as below: 
eg:

```
0: [...],
1: [...],
2: 0
```

the zero is the `return 0;` from the php side,
The problem is when I `console.log` the 3rd property it is `undefined` or when I `parseInt` it, it returns `NaN` while the 3rd property of the returned data as shown is zero.

this is the actual `console.log`:

`0
:
"{"0":2,"id":2,"1":"0.jpg","image":"0.jpg","2":"Proj 1","title":"Proj 1","3":"some description here about the course!","desc":"some description here about the course!","4":"sinawic","teacher":"sinawic","5":0,"sell_count":0,"6":"1997.05.05","date_released":"1997.05.05","7":97,"preview":97,"8":0,"likes":0,"9":0,"post_point":0,"10":0,"post_cash":0}"
1
:
"["jquery","vue"]"
2
:
"[{"lesson_num":1,"topic_name":"pre"}]"
3
:
"{"0":"sinawic","username":"sinawic","1":"web design, React, VUE, javascript","fields_name":"web design, React, VUE, javascript","2":"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe","description":"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe","3":"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%","ranks":"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%"}"
5
:
0`

and this is the data `echo` to the api:

`{"0":"{\"0\":2,\"id\":2,\"1\":\"0.jpg\",\"image\":\"0.jpg\",\"2\":\"Proj 1\",\"title\":\"Proj 1\",\"3\":\"some description here about the course!\",\"desc\":\"some description here about the course!\",\"4\":\"sinawic\",\"teacher\":\"sinawic\",\"5\":0,\"sell_count\":0,\"6\":\"1997.05.05\",\"date_released\":\"1997.05.05\",\"7\":98,\"preview\":98,\"8\":0,\"likes\":0,\"9\":0,\"post_point\":0,\"10\":0,\"post_cash\":0}","1":"[\"jquery\",\"vue\"]","2":"[{\"lesson_num\":1,\"topic_name\":\"pre\"}]","3":"{\"0\":\"sinawic\",\"username\":\"sinawic\",\"1\":\"web design, React, VUE, javascript\",\"fields_name\":\"web design, React, VUE, javascript\",\"2\":\"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe\",\"description\":\"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe\",\"3\":\"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%\",\"ranks\":\"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%\"}","5":0}`

how could I possibly solve it.

Comment: How are you parsing the response?

Comment: show us the console.log statement.

Comment: please show some more of the code, for context. Show how you make the ajax request, receive the data, what the data (the actual JSON) looks like, and how you process it. You've missed out the code which is actually causing the issue!

Comment: `allData = JSON.parse(data);` and `percent: parseInt(allData[Object.keys(allData)[5]])`

Comment: Please add extra info the question itself using the "edit" button, thanks. Comments are for brief discussion and clarification, not for code snippets.

Comment: `allData[Object.keys(allData)[5]]` is the part of the data returned that can both have value of zero or greater than zero.

Comment: please show the actual JSON as well, as already requested. And again _please_ edit it into your question, not pasting into the comments. Thankyou.

Comment: I'm sorry how do I edit the post?

Comment: press the "edit" button right underneath the question. It's just below the little blue "javascript" and "php" tags.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had just posted an answer based on you saying the data looks like `0: [...],
1: [...],
2: 0`...but now you post something different as the output of your `console.log`. Which one is correct?? The first version would explain why you have an error. If the code is actually more like the second version, then you shouldn't have an error. Also you forgot to add your actual JS code into the question as well.

Comment: As a side issue, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: all I'm trying to do is that: get a zero valued data from api which gives me the value of `undefined` or `NaN` while having the value of zero :( why ppl even downvote!!

Comment: they probably downvoted at the time when your question was unanswerable due to lack of info. I am just revising my answer now in the light of your changed data structure. In future please try not to waste people's time by not posting enough information, and then posting incorrect information, before eventually posting the correct information. It would have been easy enough to make it accurate the first time. Thankyou.

Comment: well, thanks I didn't get a solution tho. my bad I should have posted more clearly pardon me:) @ADyson

Comment: No problem. It's a learning experience for us all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to access the item at index 5 in the Object.keys array, which would be the 6th item. However you have a gap in the key numbering - 4 is not included.

Therefore the object with the key "5" is actually the 5th item in the list of keys, and therefore accessible at index 4 - because the array of keys is zero-based, like all JS arrays. There is no 6th item - the object only has 5 keys.

I think because the object keys are numeric you have got confused between the name of the key and its position in the list of keys.

Observe the difference between the last 2 console.logs in this (runnable) example:

```js
var allData = { 0:{"0":2,"id":2,"1":"0.jpg","image":"0.jpg","2":"Proj 1","title":"Proj 1","3":"some description here about the course!","desc":"some description here about the course!","4":"sinawic","teacher":"sinawic","5":0,"sell_count":0,"6":"1997.05.05","date_released":"1997.05.05","7":97,"preview":97,"8":0,"likes":0,"9":0,"post_point":0,"10":0,"post_cash":0},
1:["jquery","vue"],
2:[{"lesson_num":1,"topic_name":"pre"}],
3:{"0":"sinawic","username":"sinawic","1":"web design, React, VUE, javascript","fields_name":"web design, React, VUE, javascript","2":"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe","description":"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe","3":"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%","ranks":"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%"},
5:0 };

console.log(Object.keys(allData));

console.log(allData[Object.keys(allData)[5]]);

console.log(allData[Object.keys(allData)[4]]);
```

However you could greatly simplify this. If you already know you want the item whose key is called "5" then you can simply access it directly:

```js
var allData = { 0:{"0":2,"id":2,"1":"0.jpg","image":"0.jpg","2":"Proj 1","title":"Proj 1","3":"some description here about the course!","desc":"some description here about the course!","4":"sinawic","teacher":"sinawic","5":0,"sell_count":0,"6":"1997.05.05","date_released":"1997.05.05","7":97,"preview":97,"8":0,"likes":0,"9":0,"post_point":0,"10":0,"post_cash":0},
1:["jquery","vue"],
2:[{"lesson_num":1,"topic_name":"pre"}],
3:{"0":"sinawic","username":"sinawic","1":"web design, React, VUE, javascript","fields_name":"web design, React, VUE, javascript","2":"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe","description":"this is all about me, oke? call me maybe","3":"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%","ranks":"85%, 53%, 36%, 74%, 17%"},
5:0 };

console.log(allData[5]);
```

Comment: edited the code. my actual data is an object with has 6 properties

Comment: that's quite a significant difference. Why did you show us wrong data to start with, when the question is all about the structure of the data??

Comment: well avoiding the question being too long. I tried to put a summery of the problem!

Comment: yes but it was an incorrect summary. You claimed the data was in the key called "2" when it wasn't. Hence we ended up with an answer which didn't reflect reality and wasn't helpful to you, and then I had to revise it. It also turns out that your real data has a more subtle issue - see my edited answer. This is why it's always good to give a real example if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you have been mixing objects with arrays indexing,
this must work for you:
`allData[5]` will return the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

I created two jsfiddles:

One without 5 key in array (returns undefined)
[jsfiddle without 5](https://jsfiddle.net/eqdxgapc/3/)`//
allData = {0:'abc',1:'def',2:'ghi',3:'dlsdds',4:'dasdas'};
var ret = allData[Object.keys(allData)[5]];
console.log(ret);`

Second with 5 kry in array (return real value)
[jsfiddle with 5](https://jsfiddle.net/eqdxgapc/4/)`//
allData = {0:'abc',1:'def',2:'ghi',3:'dlsdds',4:'dasdas',5:'sddsds'};
var ret = allData[Object.keys(allData)[5]];
console.log(ret);`

Compare and you can see the difference

Comment: edited the code. my actual data is an object with has 6 properties